# How can I reinstall the 64-bit version of MSO2013 if I've purchased a Dell computer with MSO2013 32-bit installed?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, microsoft-office, 32-bit, microsoft-access

W7/64. I'm a SQL Server developer dealing with the mess described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270453/ms-access-db-engine-32-bit-with-office-64-bit/14982382), which is that the 32- and 64-bit versions of the MSA10 engine cannot coexist on a single server.

This problem might be solved by replacing MSO2013 32-bit with the 64-bit version.

Supposedly you can do this here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/download-back-up-restore-microsoft-office-products-FX103427465.aspx

But after a messy sign-in process and typing in my product key, this just results in a download of a file like "C:\Users\me\Downloads\Setup.x86.en-US_ProfessionalRetail_MY-PRODUCT-KEY_TX_PR_.exe".

This charming little executable installs/re-installs 32-bit MSO2013 without prompting, **even if it's already installed** (I'm still fixing all of the things this broke).

At no point am I given the option to download a 64-bit version.

[These instruction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA102840825.aspx)s are no extra help as they seem to assume I have a DVD.  Since this is the year 2014, I don't.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Its reinstalling the x86 version because thats the X86 setup.  You need the x64 setup.  Which normally shares the same filename except it contains `x64` instead of `x86`.  Try entering the link to the file by hand and change the x86 to x64.  Of course that likely would install the 64-bit version of Office. ( You don't need 64-bit of MSO if your installing the 32-bit version of Office ).

Comment: Changing the architecture in the download string works:  https://c2rsetup.officeapps.live.com/c2r/download.aspx?ProductreleaseID=ProfessionalRetail&language=en-US&platform=x64&token=MY-PRODUCT-KEY&TaxRegion=PR&Source=O15PKC&version=O15GA.  Will report back on the results.